# Combining dataframes with unequal rows in R

Tags: r

Say I have two dataframes,

DataFrame A

```
id x y 
a  1 2
b  2 3
b  2 4
c  4 3
a  3 7
c  3 4
a  1 0
```

DataFrame B

```
id x q
a  1 3.5
a  3 5.7
b  2 4
c  3 2.5
c  4 5.5
```

Dataframe B has a unique pair of id and x columns.

I want to combine B with A based on the columns id and x such that if there are multiple entries of same id,x in A, they get the same entries of q corresponding to that id,x.

Result wanted:

```
id x y q
a  1 2 3.5
b  2 3 4
b  2 4 4
c  4 3 5.5
a  3 7 5.7
c  3 4 2.5
a  1 0 3.5
```

I have tried using merge but it does not repeat q values, just puts NA there. Thanks.

Comment: `merge(A, B)` does it. I don't see `NA`s.

Comment: Maybe your real `A` and `B` have more column names in common than in this example you gave us?

Comment: Are your `x` columns numeric or integer? Integer would be better. Checking if two numerics are equal is always subject to rounding points errors, so that could be why your are not getting as many matches as you expected.

Comment: Thanks. Stupid mistake. I initially had assigned same levels for A and B but renamed A's id levels in the code. I will remove the question. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what your are looking for. You can merge by more than one column

```
A <- data.frame(id=c("a","b","b","c","a","c","a"), x=c(1,2,2,4,3,3,1), y=c(2,3,4,3,7,4,0))

B <- data.frame(id=c("a","a","b","c","c"),x=c(1,3,2,3,4), q=c(3.5,5.7,4,2.5,5.5))

C <- merge(A,B, by=c(1,2))

   id x y   q
1  a 1 2 3.5
2  a 1 0 3.5
3  a 3 7 5.7
4  b 2 3 4.0
5  b 2 4 4.0
6  c 3 4 2.5
7  c 4 3 5.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
merge(A, B, by = c('id', 'x')
```

Further information: [Quick-R](http://statmethods.net/management/merging.html)